# Easy way to check FormatString is valid?

Tags: c#, formatting, format-string

Is there an easy way to check if a format string is valid? For example the following is code that we use to test a number format string;

```
public static bool IsValidFormatStringNumber(string FormatString)
{
    try
    {
        const decimal number = 0.056m;
        var formattedNumber = number.ToString(FormatString);
        return formattedNumber.Length > 0;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

We're trying to catch an exception or determine if the resulting string has no length. This test fails however as a format string of "hsibbur" (Any rubbish) results in a string of "hsaibbur", which has length.

We want to do the same test for Percent and Date format string.

Comment: Is checking `toString` on a basic type basically like `x=1;if(x!=1)throw error;`? I don't see getting so granular that you'd need to test a string format (unless I'm missing something, or you need better rounding, or ...) -- EDIT: Are you trying to brute-force possible IFormatProviders?

Comment: But a format string of "hsibbur" _is_ valid!

Comment: Also, how about only catching `FormatException`? You're hiding any _real_ exceptions you might get.

Comment: There's a category of code that never needs extra checking or elaborate contract schemes.  On top of the heap is the code that turns program state into something readable by a human.  First thing you see, first thing you'll fix when it is broken.

Comment: Good responses so far. We need to test if a format string is valid because we are allowing the user to specify format strings for Percent, Numbers and Date. These are advanced settings and unless they are valid, will result in exceptions being thrown elsewhere in the program. To counter this, we'd like to run a check to see if it's valid before we persist it to the database.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to check for [standard format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), just check that your format strings are part of that list.

If you want to check for [custom format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (that are not "Other" or "Literal strings"), you can probably craft a regex to do it.

Other than that, since format strings can be *arbitrary* strings, I don't think validation even *applies*.

Comment: Thanks Jordão. Your last point is a good one and is one of the main reasons we want to allow the user to enter a valid one. Although any format string can be entered, it results in exceptions being thrown further downstream. Better to just enforce a correct/valid format string.

Answer (score 1):

If FormatString is equal to formattedNumber, that could be another case for returning false.