# Check if given string is valid format string for converting DateTime

Tags: c#, string, validation, string-formatting, datetime-format

**TLDR;**

I need to validate whether a given input string is a valid "*format string*" for parsing DateTime. For example,

- `yy-mm-dd` is valid
- `yy-aaaaaaa123` is not valid

---

I am working on a [program](https://github.com/kolappannathan/simple-csv-logger/blob/master/src/nk.logger.csv/Logger.cs) which accepts Date format as an input from the user. Below is my stripped out the code

```csharp
private string datetimeFormat;

public Logger(string dateFormat)
{
    datetimeFormat = dateFormat;
}

...
...
...

// Inside some function
string pretext = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString(datetimeFormat)},{logLevel},";
```

I need to add validation for the `dateFormat` string input.

I am thinking of having many possible combinations in an array and accept only those strings. But is there any other way to validate?

---

**Updates**:

My input string does not contain any date. This is not a duplicate of the [specified question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19019718/5407188).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7974597/5407188) is not about DateTime at all.

Comment: @SᴇM That is a completely unrelated question. My string does not contain any date.

Comment: Technically, `yy-aaaaaaa123` is valid: two digit year followed by `-aaaaaaa123`; e.g. `"98-aaaaaaa123"` will be parsed as `1 Jan 1998 0:00:00`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I need to have valid Date Time formats only. How to check that?

Comment: @KolappanNathan Valid in which context? If you exactly know what's valid for you, then create an array of valid formats and use `Contains`, ie `if(validFormats.Contains(inputFormat))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to check FormatString is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974597/easy-way-to-check-formatstring-is-valid). While this pertains to number formatting, the same answer applies to date format strings.

Comment: @SᴇM The final output should contain only DateTime nothing else.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The suggested question is not about date time at all.

Comment: ... which I commented on: "While this pertains to number formatting, the same answer applies to date format strings."

Comment: Some formats like `dd-mm-yyyy`, are *valid*, look *good*, but **erroneous**: *Days*-**Minutes**-*Years*. Probably, you may want to enumerate reasonable formats and let user choose separators: `dd-MM-yyyy`, `dd/MM/yyyy`, `dd.MM.yyyy` etc.

Comment: @HereticMonkey's dupe is probably what you want (just use [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to tailor it to dates instead). Although it depends on how "valid" you want to be. Something like `yyyy-yy--yyy---yyyy` is completely stupid, but it's "valid".

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I am considering Enum / Array approach. But wanted to check if there is any other way before I go that route.

Comment: _"I am thinking of having many possible combinations in an array and accept only those strings."_ - this is the correct solution

Comment: See also [How to validate DateTime format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11696060/215552)

Comment: WHY are you allowing the user to specify their date format?   There are only a few standard ones, and they are well supported.  ISO8601 is there for a reason.

Comment: What do you consider "only DateTime nothing else"? The most commonly-used ISO-8601 formats use a "T" between the date and the time - what makes that "T" acceptable, but not "aaaaaaa"? Would you want to accept "yyyyTMMTdd"? Fundamentally you need to define "valid date time format" much more precisely than you have done so far.

Comment: The most robust way and maybe the simplest thing that comes to my mind is providing user with something like a a drop-down to choose from. This is how you can bypass the burden & complexity of validating user input.

Comment: First you need to tell us what is valid for you. Example with 1 valid format and 1 invalid format is not enough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of depends on what you mean by "valid" and how important you think the "only `DateTime`, nothing else" restriction is to you.

Here are a few rules that we can use to test format strings, with some express limitations:

1. Must be suitable for passing to `DateTime.ToString(string format)` to convert a `DateTime` value to string.
2. Must be usable to parse the output of rule 1 into a valid `DateTime` value.
3. The output of rule 2 must not contain a time portion.
4. Optionally, the output of rule 2 should be the same as the input within a defined range of accuracy.

These will be good enough for many uses, as long as you are expecting that the output be a fully specified date.  Year, month and day must be specified.  Here's some code to test against those rules:

```
static System.Globalization.CultureInfo DateTimeProvider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
const System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles ParseExactStyle = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None;
static DateTime[] DateSamples = new[]
    {
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Today,
        DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Today.Day),
        DateTime.Parse("10-Jan-2000"),
        DateTime.Parse("01-Oct-1990"),
        DateTime.Parse("13-Feb-1901")
    };

public static bool IsValidDateFormat(string format, out string result)
{
    var maxDifference = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    foreach (var sample in DateSamples)
    {       
        // Rule 1: Must be suitable for '.ToString(...)'
        string sampleString;
        try
        {
            sampleString = sample.ToString(format);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            result = $"Failed rule 1: {e.Message}";
            return false;
        }

        // Rule 2: Must be able to parse the produced string
        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(sampleString, format, DateTimeProvider, ParseExactStyle, out var parsed))
        {
            result = $"Failed rule 2: does not parse it's own output. '{sampleString}'";
            return false;
        }

        // Rule 3: No time values.
        if (parsed != parsed.Date)
        {
            result = $"Failed rule 3: No time values. '{sampleString}' => #{parsed}#";
            return false;
        }

        // Rule 4: Difference must be less than maxDifference
        TimeSpan difference = sample < parsed ? parsed - sample : sample - parsed;
        if (difference >= maxDifference)
        {
            result = $"Failed rule 4: difference '{difference}' too large.";
            return false;
        }
    }

    result = "OK";
    return true;
}
```

(This sets the `result` out parameter to a description of why the format string failed, or OK if it passed, but you might prefer to return a simple enum value.)

This validates on all sorts of weird formats, including those with extra non-contextual - or at least non-time - characters.  The samples include a few tests against time values, order reversal and so on.

There are some limitations however:

- `TryParseExact` does not work with [standard format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) like `d`, 'F', etc.
- Nor does it work with the 3+ digit year format (`yyy`) and other stretching formats.
- The samples include a test that prevents 2-digit years being used.

In short, it's good enough for simple work.  You can trim it back a bit.